# Specify the start value of identity column

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have an identity column

```
@DatabaseField(useGetSet = true, generatedId = true,index=true)
private long saleTicket;
```

Right now when database is created than it starts from 1,is there any way to specify the initial value for this column.

Like I want to start it from 50 than 1.

Answer (score 2):

In some databases, you could use `generatedIdSequence` and configurate that sequence manually.
However, SQLite does not use sequences.

You could set `allowGeneratedIdInsert` and manually set the ID of the first object to 50.

Comment: +1 Although the real answer is that you shouldn't care what the generated-id was.